# how to read the inputs in the scanner in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to display the name of the student that has a higher gpa. 
I want to know how to limit the input in the scanner like I want to have just 2 students, so I'm gonna calculate their gap and return the one with the highest score, please help.

I used the method scanner as showed below

```
public double computerGPA() {

    double score;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the sutdent quiz score:");
    double score1 = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("enter the student test score:");
    double score2 = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("enter the student assigments score");
    double score3 = sc.nextDouble();
    sc.close();
    score = 0.2 * score1 + 0.5 * score2 + 0.3 * score3;

    return score;
   }
}
```

```
if((student1.computerGPA())<(student2.computerGPA())) {
    System.out.println("the student "+student2.name+"has higher GPA"); 
} 
if((student2.computerGPA())<(student1.computerGPA())) {
    System.out.println("the student "+student1.name+"has higher GPA"); 
} 
if((student1.computerGPA())==(student2.computerGPA())) { 
    System.out.println("the two students had the same GPA"); 
}
```

Comment: if((student1.computerGPA())<(student2.computerGPA())) {
   System.out.println("the student "+student2.name+"has higher GPA");
  }
  if((student2.computerGPA())<(student1.computerGPA())) {
   System.out.println("the student "+student1.name+"has higher GPA");
  }
  if((student1.computerGPA())==(student2.computerGPA())) {
   System.out.println("the two students had the same GPA");
  }
  
  
 }
}

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "limit the input" ? You're currently reading 3 doubles when you call `computerGPA`, which seems already limited to me. If I had to guess your problem I'd say that 1) you should add a `nextLine()` once the 3 doubles have been read so that the next call to `nextDouble()` reads from the next line and 2) you shouldn't close the scanner since it closes the underlying input stream which will make a second call to the method fail

Answer (score 0):

If i'm reading this right you're going to want a private double in your student class and instead of returning the score value to the program you can just have a void method which sets the students private double to that score

```
    private double studentScore;

        public static void computerGPA() {



    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the sutdent quiz score:");
    double score1=sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("enter the student test score:");
    System.out.println("enter the student assigments score");
    double score3=sc.nextDouble();
    sc.close();

    studentScore =0.2*score1+0.5*score2+0.3*score3;
```

then you can just have a get method for your two student objects and compare it that way

```
  if (student1.getGPAScore() > student2.getGPAScore()) {
  System.out.println("Student 1 has a higher score");
  } else {
   System.out.println("Student 2 has a higher score");
  }
```

Hope this makes sense

Comment: By the time you call the method a second time the System.in InputStream has been closed and calling `sc.nextDouble()` will raise an exception. Example here : https://ideone.com/YXmjY7. A solution would be to pass the scanner to the computerGPA/getGPAScore method and have the caller manage the scanner creation & closing

Answer (score 0):

If you want comparison of only 2 student than you should use method `computerGPA()` only 2 times. You are limiting the input in the scanner by defining how menu times you use it. With your code:

```
if((student1.computerGPA())<(student2.computerGPA())) {
   System.out.println("the student "+student2.name+"has higher GPA"); 
} 
if((student2.computerGPA())<(student1.computerGPA())) {
   System.out.println("the student "+student1.name+"has higher GPA"); 
} 
if((student1.computerGPA())==(student2.computerGPA())) { 
   System.out.println("the two students had the same GPA"); 
}
```

because you call `computerGPA()` 6 times you are giving a user possibility to enter scores for 6 different students. You can solve this with:

```
public class Student {

    private String name;

    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double computerGPA(Scanner sc) {
        System.out.println("Enter the QUIZ TEST ASSIGMENT scores for student " + name
            + " (for example: \"10 9 8\"):");

        /**A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern,
        which by default matches whitespace. 
        This way you can simplify input.
        But your code, where you ask specifically for every value, would also work.**/
        float score1 = sc.nextFloat();
        float score2 = sc.nextFloat();
        float score3 = sc.nextFloat();
        return 0.2 * score1 + 0.5 * score2 + 0.3 * score3;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student student1 = new Student("Boo");
        Student student2 = new Student("Foo");

        double student1ComputerGPA;
        double student2computerGPA;
        //Scanner must be outside computerGPA() method because of Aaron's comments.
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            //Call method computerGPA() only 2 times for 2 students.
            student1ComputerGPA = student1.computerGPA(sc);
            student2computerGPA = student2.computerGPA(sc);
        }

        //I use ternary operator instead of if() statements. Result is same.
        String result = student1ComputerGPA < student2computerGPA ?
            "The student \"" + student2.name + "\" has higher GPA."
            : (student2computerGPA < student1ComputerGPA ? 
                "The student \"" + student1.name + "\" has higher GPA." : 
                "The two students had the same GPA.");

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that i want the code to mention the students name in the sentence enter Enter the student's QUIZ TEST ASSIGMENT scores

Comment: @Kaoutar Bentalha I edited my answer. Sentence now also contains name of specific student.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student{

    String name;
    boolean calculated;
    double score;

    Student(String name){
        this.name=name;
        this.calculated=false;
    }

    public double computerGPA() {

        if (!this.calculated) {

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("enter the sutdent quiz score:");
            double score1 = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("enter the student test score:");
            double score2 = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("enter the student assigments score");
            double score3 = sc.nextDouble();
            //sc.close();
            score = 0.2 * score1 + 0.5 * score2 + 0.3 * score3;
            this.calculated=true;

        }
        return score;

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Student student1= new Student("name1");
        Student student2=new Student("name2");


        if((student1.computerGPA())<(student2.computerGPA())) {
            System.out.println("the student "+student2.name+"has higher GPA"); 
        } 
        if((student2.computerGPA())<(student1.computerGPA())) {
            System.out.println("the student "+student1.name+"has higher GPA"); 
        } 
        if((student1.computerGPA())==(student2.computerGPA())) { 
            System.out.println("the two students had the same GPA"); 
        }
    }
}
```